# Sequence that tends to $0$ a.e. but has constant integral

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ can we find a sequence of measurable functions $f_n\geq 0$ s.t. $\int f_n d\mu =1$ but $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e.?

This property holds e.g. when $X=\mathbb{R}$ with $f_n=n \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$. I wonder if there exists a measure space that the above property is not true.

Comment: Let $\mu(A) = 0$ for every $A \in \mathcal{M}$ :)

Comment: A finite space with the counting measure will works.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if the measure space is $\sigma$-finite. In this case, there exists a sequence of disjoint measurable sets $(A_n)$ of finite (and positive) measure. Defining $f_n:=\mathbf 1(A_n)/\mu(A_n)$, we get $\int f_n\mathrm d\mu=1$ and $f_n\to 0$ almost everywhere. 
This also works if there exists a measurable subset $S$ such that the induced measure is $\sigma$-finite.

The property may not hold in finite measured space with the counting measure because the (almost) everywhere convergence is equivalent to the convergence in $\mathbb L^1$. It is however true if we replace the word "finite" by "infinite".